# Extracting list of urls from url using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract information about website similarity from this link:

https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/amazon.com

I am looking at class='site', trying to extract information from

```
<a href="/siteinfo/ebay.com" class="truncation">ebay.com</a>
```

but I can see only one value. Could it be possible to extract all the 4 values and related overlap score?

What I am trying to achieve is a table which includes this information

```
W                      amazon.com              
eBay.com                   70.1
pinterest.com              54.7
wikipedia.org              51.3
facebook.com               50.4
```

I have tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
print([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select("span.site")])
```

but this seems to be enough for getting information because of some wrong parameters in the code.

Comment: Appears you want `span.truncation` , `a.trunctation`, or `div.site`

Comment: thank you for your comment, OneCricketeer. I can see from inspect tool on Google Chrome only the span for overlap score and site. I cannot see the tags you mentioned

Comment: this page uses `JavaScript` to add elements - but `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` can't run JavaScript - you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`

Comment: That's not true @furas. While it does use JS for some features, the table the OP refers too is loaded normally and can be detected without the need for a headless browser

Comment: `a.truncation` is the element that you've shown in the question. And the scores look like `<span class="truncation">38.0</span>`, so `span.truncation`. For site classes, those are only on div elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS selectors were a good start but were too narrow. The CSS Selectors that you should have used were:

- Websites: `#card_mini_audience .site>a`
- Scores: `#card_mini_audience .overlap>.truncation`

These selectors narrow the focus to the div where the table is stored and then makes use of the class labels to extract your desired information.

I have attached some example code below that solves your issue. I just printed the results to the screen but it can easily be changed to do whatever you want with the values.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Getting the website and processing it
url = "https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/amazon.com"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

#Using CSS Selectors to grab content
websites = soup.select("#card_mini_audience .site>a")   #Selects the websites in the table
scores = soup.select("#card_mini_audience .overlap>.truncation")    #Selects the corresponding scores

#Goes through the list and extracts just the text
websites = [website.text.strip() for website in websites]
scores = [float(score.text.strip()) for score in scores]    #Converts the scores to floats

#Ordinary print to screen. You can change this to add to a dataframe or whatever else you want for your project
for pair in zip(websites, scores):
    print(pair)
```

The output looks like this:

```
('ebay.com', 70.1)
('pinterest.com', 54.7)
('wikipedia.org', 51.3)
('facebook.com', 50.4)
('reddit.com', 49.6)
```